# Splitting Access Cells Based On Decimal Point

Tags: ms-access

Currently I have an Access 2013 database table with a column in it that has some values;

```
Value1: 90.1244.1234

Value2: 90.1295
```

I would like to split these out into 3 columns based on the decimal point.

```
Column1    Column2    Column 3
90         1244       1234
```

However, when i try to split these out, the values that only have 1 decimal point, throws a #Func! error. Instead of the #Func! error, i would like to leave the cell blank.

**The code i am using:**

```
First Split: Left$([JDE Account Number],InStr([JDE Account Number],".")-1)

Middle Split: Mid([JDE Account Number],InStr([JDE Account Number],".")+1,InStrRev([JDE Account Number],".")-InStr([JDE Account Number],".")-1)

Last Split: Right$([JDE Account Number],Len([JDE Account Number])-InStrRev([JDE Account Number],"."))
```

Its the middle split that is causing the #FUNC! error as sometimes the values only have 1 decimal place.

Is there any way to somehow leave the middle cell blank if the value only has one decimal place and not two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a small function:

```
Public Function SplitString(ByVal Triple As String, ByVal Element As Integer) As Variant

    Dim Elements    As Variant
    Dim TriplePart  As Variant

    Elements = Split(Triple, ".")

    If UBound(Elements) >= Element - 1 Then
        TriplePart = Elements(Element - 1)
    Else
        TriplePart = Null
    End If

    SplitString = TriplePart

End Function
```

And use that in your Query as an expression:

```
Column1: SplitString(Nz([JDE Account Number]),1)
Column2: SplitString(Nz([JDE Account Number]),2)
Column3: SplitString(Nz([JDE Account Number]),3)
```

Comment: Apologies @Gustav i forgot to mark this an answered

Comment: Wauw! Better late than never. Thanks!